# Type-of-address of the sender number (SMS)

Tags: parsing, sms

I would like to know what kind of `type-of-address` of the sender number exist. For example, the PDU below contains `91` `type-of-address`:

07`91`9742020096F6400B`91`9742039333F7

`91`  means international format of the phone number and I have to add `+` before this number. Sometimes I face type-of-address such as `D0`, `C8` and so on. So what do they mean? Where can I find information about it? Thanks in advance.

--UPDATED--

I have found the program called `PDUspy`. It can recognise `type-of-address`. So I have found that `D0` - `Alpha (acc. to TS 03.38)` and the number is represented as text, for example `Nikolas`. `C8` - `subscriber number`. But what do they mean and how to parse these numbers depending on its type?

Answer (score 3):

The TON/NPI information can be found on section 9.1.2.5 of [3GPP TS 23.040](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/23040.htm).
The address value (phone number) are BCD left coded, padded with optional 'F' to make it even and then swapped.

Example of parsing the APDU data from an SMS proactive command (also need to refer to [3GPP TS 11.14](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/1114.htm))

```
D0 16 81 03 06 13 01 82 02 81 83 0B 0B 01 00 03 81 00 F7 00 F2 02 70 6C

PROACTIVE SIM COMMAND - SEND SHORT MESSAGES - GSM MODE [D0]
  Command Details Tag [81]
        Length : 03
        Command Number : 06
        Command Type : Send Short Message
        Command Qualifier : 01H, 0000 0001 (SMS packing by the ME required)
  Device Identities Tag [82]
        Length : 02
        Source device : SIM
        Destination device : Network
  SMS TPDU Tag [0B]
        Length : 0B
        TP-MTI : SMS Submit/Submit Report
        TP-RD  : Instruct the SC to accept an SMS-SUBMIT
        TP-VPF : TP-VP field not present
        TP-RP  : TP-Reply Path parameter is not set in this SMS SUBMIT/DELIVER
        TP-UDHI : The TP-UD field contains only the short message
        TP-SRR  : a report is not requested
        TP-MR : 00
        TP-DA : 
              Number of digits: 3
              TON/NPI : Unknown - ISDN/Telephone numbering plan
              Address Value : "007"
        TP-PID : 00
        TP-DCS : F2
        TP-UDL : 02
        TP-UD : "pl"
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is represented as text, you can decode it with 7bit type. CEF4FACD0ECF01=Nikolas